# How can I create an Arraylist which not refers to another one?

Tags: java, arraylist, reference, clone, copy-constructor

I know that when you create an ArrayList and when declaring it you refer it to another ArrayList it only refers to the other so changes made to the second one change the first one. But I got confused when facing this problem.

```
ArrayList <Productos> d3 = abd.dadesProductos();
ArrayList <Productos> dades2 = new ArrayList <Productos>();
System.out.println("before clear() + size= "+d3.get(i).configurables.size());//43
dades2.add(d3.get(i));
dades2.get(dades2.size()-1).configurables.clear();
System.out.println("after clear() + size= "+d3.get(i).configurables.size());//0
```

The problem is that after clearing the parameter configurables(another arraylist) from the last item added to dades2 it also clears it from d3 which I don't want this to happen at all... Why is this happening if I create a that ArrayList as `new ArrayList <Productos>();`

I will appreaciate any help.

Some extra information.

I have tried to create a new Constructor like this:

```
Productos(Productos p)
    {
        this(p.entity_id, p.model, p.sku, p.name, p.weight, p.visibility, p.material, p.attribute_set_name, p.image, p.category_ids, p.category_ids2, p.color, p.color2, p.color3, p.cpsp_enable, p.created_at, p.description, p.colorswatch_disabled_category, p.colorswatch_disabled_product, p.msrp_display_actual_price_type, p.options_container, p.fcpm_enable, p.is_recurring, p.image_label, p.manage_stock, p.manufacturer, p.max_sale_qty, p.meta_description, p.meta_keyword, p.meta_title, p.category_positions, p.price, p.type_id, p.fcpm_second_attribute, p.fcpm_template, p.fcpm_template_position, p.short_description, p.fcpm_showfdd, p.fcpm_show_grandtotal, p.fcpm_second_layout, p.fcpm_show_link, p.fcpm_checkbox, p.fcpm_show_image, p.fcpm_show_rowtotal, p.fcpm_show_stock, p.special_price, p.special_from_date, p.special_to_date, p.status, p.tax_class_id, p.tier_price, p.url_key, p.updated_at, p.url_path, p.dimensions, p.mindeco, p.talla, p.trang1, p.trang2, p.trang3, p.trang4, p.trang5, p.tprice1, p.tprice2, p.tprice3, p.tprice4, p.tprice5, p.maxCols, p.marcPrio, p.configurables, p.marcajes);
    }
```

And same think happens. I think it's because I assign the ArrayList configurables by reference.

I've tried to do something with deep clone with no success. Don't understand how to use it at all.

**SOLUTION**

```
dades2.add(new Productos(d3.get(i)));
```

```
Productos(Productos p)
    {
        this(p.entity_id, p.model, p.sku, p.name, p.weight, p.visibility, p.material, p.attribute_set_name, p.image, p.category_ids, p.category_ids2, p.color, p.color2, p.color3, p.cpsp_enable, p.created_at, p.description, p.colorswatch_disabled_category, p.colorswatch_disabled_product, p.msrp_display_actual_price_type, p.options_container, p.fcpm_enable, p.is_recurring, p.image_label, p.manage_stock, p.manufacturer, p.max_sale_qty, p.meta_description, p.meta_keyword, p.meta_title, p.category_positions, p.price, p.type_id, p.fcpm_second_attribute, p.fcpm_template, p.fcpm_template_position, p.short_description, p.fcpm_showfdd, p.fcpm_show_grandtotal, p.fcpm_second_layout, p.fcpm_show_link, p.fcpm_checkbox, p.fcpm_show_image, p.fcpm_show_rowtotal, p.fcpm_show_stock, p.special_price, p.special_from_date, p.special_to_date, p.status, p.tax_class_id, p.tier_price, p.url_key, p.updated_at, p.url_path, p.dimensions, p.mindeco, p.talla, p.trang1, p.trang2, p.trang3, p.trang4, p.trang5, p.tprice1, p.tprice2, p.tprice3, p.tprice4, p.tprice5, p.maxCols, p.marcPrio, p.marcajes);
        ArrayList <Configurable>configs=p.configurables;
        for(int i=0;i<configs.size();i++)
        {
            this.configurables.add(new Configurable(configs.get(i)));
        }
    }
```

```
Configurable(Configurable c)
    {
        this(c.codip, c.codic, c.sku, c.color, c.color2, c.color3, c.talla, c.price, c.image, c.trang1, c.trang2, c.trang3, c.trang4, c.trang5, c.tprice1, c.tprice2, c.tprice3, c.tprice4, c.tprice5);
    }
```

As it seemed creating a new constructor for `Productos` wasn't enough I also created a new constructor for `Configurable` and copying the items with a for one by one on `Productos` constructor. It seems it works now.

Comment: You're using `i` in there  as in `d3.get(i)` -- is some of this code within a for loop?

Comment: do you mean make a copy?

Comment: Yes, I do hovercraft. There is a for between the part when I define both arraylists and the part when I do the first `println` to check the result

Comment: Glad it worked out for you. It might be worth considering a builder class for your Configurable class, since that copy constructor's call is pretty unmanageable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The reason this is happening is that you're altering the object in the List, not the List itself. Both Lists here contain the same object within them, so when you `get()` from one, you're getting the same object contained within the other List too.

The way to get around this is to insert a copy of your `Productos` class into the new array, instead of the already created object. Depending on the complexity of your Productos class, you can create a copy constructor, or implement `clone()` on it to copy it.

Comment: I have tried creating a copy constructor of `Productos` but same thing happens. When assigning it's like this: `dades2.add(new Productos(d3.get(i)));`

Comment: inside the object, do you copy the list or copy the list by assigning the list or creating a new list and copying the members of the list? see my remark about shallow/ deep copy.

Answer (score 2):

The issues is not the array list, but your assignment:

```
dades2.add(d3.get(i));
```

Your objects need to implement some type of `clone()` function where they create a new instance filled with the same data as the original one. 
So the  line above should become

```
dades2.add( d3.get(i).clone() );
```

A further topic you may want to research is the difference then between shallow copy and deep copy.

Comment: Assuming that `configurables` is a `List`, you wouldn't be able to clone the object pointed by the reference returned by `d3.get(i)` that way.

Comment: That is why I mentioned shallow/ depp copy :-) as far as I can see it depends on the implementation of clone()

Answer (score 0):

To create an independent copy of your ArrayList, you need to iterate on each of the items and clone them individually, putting the clones into your new ArrayList as you go. Here is an example demonstrating:

```
public static List<Productos> cloneList(List<Productos> list) {
    List<Productos> clone = new ArrayList<Productos>(list.size());
    for(Productos item: list) clone.add(item.clone());
    return clone;
}
```

For the above method to work you have to make your Productos object implement the Cloneable interface and overwrite the clone() method. If need be, you can read up on that process here: http://howtodoinjava.com/2012/11/08/a-guide-to-object-cloning-in-java/